# li elements overflowing Card container and increases parent container to fit itself

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using ant design library. So I wanted to put a list in a card body.

```
const MyCard = ({data}) = > {

  return (
    <Card
      title={"Hello"}
      style={{ flex: '1 1 auto' }}
      bodyStyle={{
        padding: 0,
      }}
    >
      <List
        style={{overflow:'auto'}}
        dataSource={data}
        renderItem={(item) => (
          <li>
            hello
          </li>
        )}
      />
  </Card>
  )
}
```

[image]

When this gets rendered the `li`s  and the `ul`overflow the `<Card>` component. `ul` Increases to fit its children `li`s. But the `Card.body` does not increase its size. I want to make the list stay inside the card body please help.

I have tried `overflow: auto, overflow: hidden` for all card, card body, list

Comment: I hope are you facing design problem.
with flex is that possible you share screenshot.
and you can try flex-wrap
or visit https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @NavedKhan : I don't think this is because of display flex. I have tried the default display, block  and flex. It is all the same. + I have included a screenshot

Comment: I am no expert, but doesn't the `<Card>` tag need to be closed with a `</Card>` ?

Comment: Have you tried changing flex to `flex: 1 0 auto;`?

Comment: @MihailMinkov Yes

Comment: Could you add an example of the resulting code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205845/discussion-between-inyoung-kim-and-mihail-minkov).

Comment: adding `overflow:auto` to` div ant-card-body`  and removing `overflow:auto`from ul did not work

Comment: Added`height: 100%` to `bodyStyle`, the scroll bar appeared but the height was not matching the body of Card, instead it matched the height of the Card. So not a solution but for a work around, give height to bodyStyle

Answer (score 0):

Just changing Child `Card` from `overflow: hidden` to `overflow:auto` didn't solve my problem.

Solved in two steps.

1. Changed Parent `div` from `display:flex` to `display:grid`
2. Changed Child `Card` from `overflow: hidden` to `overflow:auto`